# Determine if var is a custom Type

Tags: types, go, assertions

How to determine if the var passed to my Func is actually the Type that i want?

i have a custom Type

```
type Name string
```

and a bunch of constants of that type

```
const Fred Name = "fred"
```

and i have a func that i need to forbid any other type of input other than my custom Type ex:

```
func MyFunc(name1 Name, name2 Name) (*Person, error) {
//bunch of stuff
}
```

how i check inside my func that name1 and name2 are not strings passed to the func but exclusively the const i already defined in my type ex:

```
p, err := MyFunc(Fred,Albert) //What i want
p, err := MyFunc("fred","albert") //What i dont want to happen
```

if cannot answer my question how i can make like a Enum in Golang a type that means something and restrict other ppl to use that type i defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version? you can't create that restricting kind of enum.

Long version, there are few options:

Define a validation function on the "type":

```
func (n Name) valid() bool { //private method
    switch n {
    case Mal, Kaylee: //all the valid constants
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

This however doesn't stop someone from using `Name("fred").valid()` like @peterSO pointed out.

Use a struct with a private member in it, however they aren't "constants" per-se, an outside package can reassign them to invalid values:

```
type Name struct {
    n string
}

var (
    invalid = Name{}
    Mal     = Name{"mal"}
    Kaylee  = Name{"kaylee"}
)

func MyFunc(name1 Name, name2 Name) error {
    if name1 == invalid || name2 == invalid {
        return errors.New("invalid names")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Use numeric constants and a private array, this is the only fool-proof version really and the closest you will get to a real enum:

```
type Name uint8

var names = [...]string{
    "Mal",
    "Kaylee",
}

func (n Name) valid() bool {
    return uint8(n) < uint8(len(names))
}

func (n Name) String() string {
    if !n.valid() {
        return "invalid"
    }
    return names[n]
} 

const (
    Mal Name = iota
    Kaylee
)

func MyFunc(name1 Name, name2 Name) error {
    if !name1.valid() || !name2.valid() {
        return errors.New("invalid names")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: At last this was the right thing to do, all the values i need have to be constants so i applied the last of your recommendations, the other answers didnt passed the goLint and neither where definitely solving as the last of your suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 4):

have your type implement an interface that is not exported

```
type Name string

type Private interface{
     private()
}

func (n Name) private() {}

func MyFunc(name1, name2 Private) (*Person, error) {
    //bunch of stuff
}
```

Comment: This a very cleaver idea, although adds run-time overhead of asserting the interface. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @OneOfOne I suppose you could also have private() return Name for convenience `interface private { private() Name }`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I *think* just passing an interface in itself requires runtime overhead, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Sorry at the end this wasn't foolProof, i needed const to reduce heap and didnt passed golint

Comment: @Eefret I ended up editing my answer to export the interface, this should solve the golint warning